# Deleting some files from project downloaded from GitHub if I want to put the project in another GitHub repository and to push the commits there?

Tags: file, github, project

From November 2019 to May 2020 I've been creating Project A on Computer A and I've been pushing the commits into Repository A in GitHub.

Some days ago I downloaded Project A from Repository A as a zip file on Computer B. I want to continue the developing of Project A on Computer B and to stop pushing the commits into Repository A in GitHub and to create Repository B in GitHub and when I make some changes to push the commits there.

Do I have to delete some files from the downloaded Project A before putting it into Repository B so I don't get errors when I put it into Repository B and when I start making commits in that repository?

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the repository as a zip, you have only downloaded a snapshot of repo A HEAD, not all its commit.

That means, on computer B, as you have to do (once you have created a new empty repository B on GitHub) is:

- extract repoA.zip
- `cd repoA`
- `git config --global init.defaultBranch main`
- `git init .`
- `git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/repoB`
- `git add .`

At this point, you can add everything: `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes`, `.gitmodules`, ... All those files are part of the repository.

- `git commit -m "Inport repoA"`
- `git push -u origin main`

Comment: I know how to publish an existing project to GitHub. My question was do I have to remove some files from Project A before publishing it into Repository B for having been downloaded from Repository A previously? For example the project I downloaded from Repository A has `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` files in it. Do I have to delete these files before publishing in Repository B and are there other files I have to remove from Project A so I don't get any errors on publishing and on pushing commits to Repository B afterwards? I updated my question making it more easy to understand.

Comment: @AnonymousUser No, those .gitxxx files are supposed to remain in the repository,  no matter whare you are pushing it to.